# Response header cached at Akamai by default?

Tags: akamai

I have a request caching for API layer of my website and the configuration is done to cache the API response for 24 hours.

But looks like the response header is also getting cached, which is being served as a TCP_HIT response and one of the response header is causing the WWW (UI) to trigger an unnecessary call.

How/where do I check the response header getting cached?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you check Pragma Headers? Cache key might give you some idea.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, only the resources are cached in CDN. The response headers would provide information for a response. Check HTTP Cache headers & Akamai Pragma headers that would provide more details about your level of caching works.

TCP_HIT indicates that the resource you are attempting to retrieve is served from Akamai CDN.
Also, Check for X-Cache-Key that would gives info about TTL of the resource retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

You can add behaviours in your configuration to manipulate response headers and remove the header you do not want to send.